# advance level matrix multiplication and manipulation r

Tags: r, subset

I have a list `A`:

```
[1]  9  7  4
```

and an array of `F` of this construction:

```
$`1`
[1] 68.6 73.3 37.9 54.8 61.0 72.0 49.8 41.7 52.0 81.0 62.0 73.5 55.0 80.0 45.0
[16] 56.4 46.7 43.3 55.0 61.0 77.5 53.0 49.5

$`2`
[1]  94.4  58.6  95.6 104.0  40.0  40.8  55.7  55.0  42.0  45.0  33.0  47.5  37.0
[14]  46.4  36.0  41.0  73.3  73.6  

$`3`
[1] 77.3 40.0 73.4 86.2 31.0 29.2 41.4 40.0 30.0 38.0 25.0 46.2
```

All I want to do is to take the first member (9) from list `A` and subtract from all the members of `$1` of array `F`, then subtract the second member (7), in the same way from all the members of `$2` of `F` and so on (PS: I have around 5.000 entries in `A` and equal entries in `F`).

Overall, take one member (in a sequence) from `A` and subtract from all members of members of a list in `F`, then next... I tried `sweep(F, 2, A)` but no solution; it's probably a simple solution but it's not working for me, please guide.

Comment: Try to use `?Map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example would be to use `mapply`.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
f <- list(1:10, 11:20, 21:30)
mapply(FUN = function(x,y){x-y}, x = f, y = a)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    9   18
# [2,]    1   10   19
# [3,]    2   11   20
# [4,]    3   12   21
# [5,]    4   13   22
# [6,]    5   14   23
# [7,]    6   15   24
# [8,]    7   16   25
# [9,]    8   17   26
#[10,]    9   18   27
```